# How to loop through a SortedList, getting both the key and the value

Tags: c#, sortedlist

The following code loops through a list and gets the values, but how would I write a similar statement that gets both the keys and the values

```
foreach (string value in list.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

e.g something like this

```
    foreach (string value in list.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.WriteLine(list.key);
}
```

code for the list is:

```
SortedList<string, string> list = new SortedList<string, string>();
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
}
```

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132335.aspx):

GetEnumerator returns an enumerator of type `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` that iterates through the `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`.

As Jon stated, you can use `var` keyword instead of writing type name of iteration variable (type will be inferred from usage):

```
foreach (var kvp in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
}
```

Comment: Or use `var` to avoid the long-winded variable declaration.

Comment: @JonSkeet agree, var is better in real life, but I wrote full type name to show what is the actual type of kvp.

Comment: That definitely makes sense - it may be worth showing both approaches.

Comment: Also from the documentation linked: _While enumerating, the sort order is maintained._ So you are `foreach`ing in the correct order (by keys, ascending).

Comment: Your answer is correct when we declare the generic sorted list like below:  SortedList<string, string> sortedlist = new SortedList<string, string>(); If we declare it simple way means without generic it won't work..

Comment: @ManasKumar this question was about generic SortedList. Non-generic version of SortedList uses DictionaryEntry objects instead of KeyValuePairs to store entries. So just use `foreach(DictionaryEntry entry in list)`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, you are correct on the System.Collections reference differences. I could not get your method to work with the non-Generic version...used ms article referenced in my post to solve (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248781/iteration-through-sortedlist/47063019#47063019)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies...

this was wrong topic (loop through values). My issue was looping through the key value pairs, not just the values.
Will leave this here if there are no objections as a possible option to get values from SortedList collection.

I just tried to figure out this error as well and my solution was to use the `DictionaryEntry` type to replace the erroring out `KeyValuePair` type.
Found from MS reference 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry(v=vs.100).aspx

In my case, I had code creating a `SortedList` type collection and neither the `var` or `KeyValuePair` types worked (`var` errored out when trying to read the key/value from the collection item and the `KeyValuePair` errored out in the initial loop definition. Both errored out with `"Specified cast is not valid"` )

So here is sample of code that worked for me:

```
SortedList _dims = GetList("mysortedlist");
foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in _dims)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value.ToString()); 
}
```

HTH

Dave

Answer (score -1):

Just iterated using the keys and get the value for each key:

```
SortedList<string, string> info = new SortedList<string, string>();

info.Add("path", "път");
info.Add("folder", "директория");
info.Add("directory", "директория");
info.Add("file", "Файл");

foreach (string key in info.Keys)
{
 Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", key, info[key]);
}
```

Comment: That's going to be *dramatically* slower, as you need to look up each key, which has a cost, and isn't any easier to use than simply iterating the pairs.

Answer (score -2):

```
 bool value = list[key];
```

this can help you.