# Iteration through SortedList

Tags: c#, sortedlist

```
SortedList<string, systemuser> Users = new SortedList<string, systemuser>();
Users.Add("username1",customobject);
Users.Add("username2",customobject);
Users.Add("username3",customobject);
```

What i'm trying to do is search the list for a specific key (i.e. a username) and return the next item in the list. If i'm at the end of the list then I need to return the item in the first position.

Not sure how to go about this, as the SortedList doesn't seem to expose an index property.

I have:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, systemuser> pair in Users)
{
    if (pair.Key == lastAllocation)
    {
        // RETURN THE ITEM IMMEDIATELY AFTER THIS ONE
    }
}
```

Any suggestion appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the next item (KeyValuePair), value, or index?

```
bool returnNextItem = false;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, systemuser> pair in Users)
{
    if (returnNextItem)
        return pair.Value;
    if (pair.Key == lastAllocation)
        returnNextItem = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First get the index of the seeking element. Then get the key for the necessary one (don't forget the module `%`). Finally access the loved one :))

```
SortedList<string, systemuser> Users = new SortedList<string, systemuser>();
Users.Add("username1",customobject);
Users.Add("username2",customobject);
Users.Add("username3",customobject);

var index = Users.IndexOfKey("username1"); // check not found if necessary
var nextItemKey = s.Keys[(index + 1) % Users.Count()];
var nextItemValue = Users.IndexOfKey(nextItemKey);
```

Comment: This is pretty close. The only issue is if the item isn't found, this will return the first item (because index will be -1). The poster didn't specify what they wanted if the name wasn't in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

The [SortedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains the methods necessary to do this. Look at `IndexOfKey` and `GetByIndex`.

Comment: He is using the generic sorted list https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.100).aspx Only the non generic version https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.100).aspx includes the GetbyIndex() method

Answer (score 1):

When you call `foreach`, what you're really doing is calling `Users.GetEnumerator();`.

That is syntactic sugar for the following:

```
KeyValuePair<String, Systemuser> pair;
IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<String, Systemuser>> enumerator = Users.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    pair = enumerator.Current;
    // your code in the foreach loop here
}
```

Easy solution is to use the enumerator manually to do what you want.

```
KeyValuePair<String, Systemuser> getSomething(String lastAllocation)
{

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<String, Systemuser>> enumerator = Users.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        if (enumerator.Current.Key == lastAllocation)
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            return enumerator.Current; // null if not another
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `new String("some string")` won't compile.

Comment: Now it compiles, but your conclusion still isn't correct.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lO45bT -- The `==` operator is overridden for `System.String`.

Comment: I think you meant `return enumerator.Current;` inside the if

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IndexOfKey` to find the position in the list of the given username.

Using the index returned, you can return the next item, or return the first item in the list.

```
var idx = Users.IndexOfKey("username2");

if (idx == (Users.Count - 1)){
    return Users.First().Key;
}
else{
    return Users.Keys[idx + 1];
    //.net 4.5+ can Users.GetByIndex()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. Not sure what you want if there is no match so we are just returning an new KeyValuePair;
Also make sure you have a using System.Linq; so you have access the ElementAt extension method.

```
   public static KeyValuePair<string, string> GetUserInfo(string username, SortedList<string, string> list)
    {
        int index = list.IndexOfKey(username);
        if(index == -1)
        {
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>();
        }

        index = index == (list.Count - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;

        return list.ElementAt(index);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, there are 2 core references for SortedList, one in System.Collections (older) and System.Collections.Generic. When dealing with System.Collections.SortedList, I was only able to use the method of iteration referenced in the Microsoft Article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is the loop where myList is the SortedList collection.

```
  for ( int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++ )  {

     Console.WriteLine( "\t{0}:\t{1}", myList.GetKey(i), myList.GetByIndex(i) );

  }
```

Dave